# Instalar RestSharp em projetos PCL Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, rest, xamarin

Como eu faço para instalar o RestSharp em um projeto PCL(Xamarin.Forms). Está dando esse erro ao instalar:

> Não foi possível instalar o pacote 'RestSharp 106.3.0-alpha0002'. 
>   Você está tentando instalar este pacote em um projeto que se destina a
>   '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile259',  mas o pacote não
>   contém nenhuma referência de assembly ou arquivo de conteúdo que seja
>   compatível com essa estrutura.  Para obter mais informações, entre em
>   contato com o autor do pacote.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta Alterar o Profile da PCL. Pode ser que a versão do RestSharp não seja compatível com a PCL.

Eu sugiro utilizar as alternativas : [Http Client](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx) ou [Refit](https://xamgirl.com/consuming-a-restful-web-service-in-xamarin-forms-using-refit-part-1/). Geralmente são minhas opções para REST.